# Comparing datasets

Tags: sas

I have 2 datasets.  1 containing the columns origin_zip(number) and destination_zip(char) and tracking_number(char) and the other containing zip.

I would like to compare these 2 datasets so I can see all the tracking numbers and destination_zips that are not in the zip column of the second dataset.

Additionally I would like to see all of the tracking_numbers and origin_zips where the origin_zips = the destination_zips.

How would I accomplish this?

```
origin_zip    destination_zip    tracking_number
12345         23456              11111
34567         45678              22222
12345         12345              33333

zip
12345
34567
23456

results_tracking_number
22222
33333
```

Comment: Post your data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this...I don't think this completely answers your question, but follow up with comments and I will help if I can...

```
data zips;
input origin_zip $ destination_zip $ tracking_number $;
datalines;
12345         23456              11111
34567         45678              22222
56789         12345              33333
;

data zip;
input zip $;
datalines;
12345
54321
34567
76543
56789
;

Proc sort data=zips;
by origin_zip;
run;

Proc sort data=zip;
by zip;
run;

Data contained not_contained;
merge zip(in=a) zips(in=b rename=(origin_zip=zip));
by zip;
if a and b then output contained;
if a and not b then output not_contained;
run;
```